# Rendering HTML : Serverside Vs Clientside

Tags: java, jquery, json, jsp

I have a complex invoice page with orderitems etc details . I will be working with these kind of forms all time . When page is loaded I am using javacode(for loops etc) and writing html in that way . 
Another thing I can do is return a json object and use javascript to build that form . What is better practice ?

FYI I am only using Java , jsps , JQuery , json .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are two absolutely different approaches.

1. When you building your page with java jsp technology it is a **server technology**. That means that you can control data on server which will be returned to clients. Representation of this data it's another question.
2. JavaScript is **client technology**, more flexible, less boilerplate, faster, but page generation depends on client javascript engine. If it disabled, you can get some problems.

If you not tied to any tech-requirements, I recommend to choose javascript, because you have the case *to get data from server*.

In case *send data to the server* server technology is preferable.

Answer (score 1):

There are many "options" for doing this. For web forms I prefer the route of javascript with a json object. js is very flexible and is very easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest json, jquery plugins... More manageable & cleaner codes

Comment: Me too, and a REST service on server side (Jersey). Jersey can represent your data in JSON. You can use JQuery also to manage ajax calls to the rest service.

Answer (score 0):

Client side rendering is generally considered slower (in terms of page load times), as was found recently when [Twitter switched back to server-side rendering from client-side](http://engineering.twitter.com/2012/05/improving-performance-on-twittercom.html) and found that their pages were loading in 1/5th the time.

It's not going to make much difference when you're running a site on a core i7 computer with 16GB of RAM; where it does matter is when you running a heavily client-side site on a mobile device or older computer. More javascript = higher RAM usage and more work for the browser to do (download, parsing, running).

Don't get me wrong, I'm a massive big fan of client-side rendering as it lets me use the awesome AngularJS. For me it about **finding a nice balance between the two**: I want a fast loading page with a rich UI experience.

So for example, if I was creating a new listings page; I'd could have the first 10 or so results, loaded with the page, from the server. Then I'd have something like a "Load more news articles" button at the bottom or the page which loads the next 10 news item asynchronously via some javascript call (e.g. jQuery $.ajax(), AngularJS $http etc) to a JSON service.

As opposed to:

- **Client-side only**: load the initial 10 news items via javascript & JSON, as your page is loading. Clicking the "Load more news articles" button, uses the same service to then load additional news items on request.
- **Server-side only**: load the initial 10 news items with the page, from the server. Clicking the "Load more news articles" button triggers a page-refresh and the next 10 news articles are returned from the server.